# How can I find if it is gold or lead with waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, frequency, density

I would find if a bowl is made of lead or gold know freqencies $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ and a vibrator induces waves at $z=0$ (and there are reflected waves). I do it with progressive plane electromagnetic waves and I have the d'alembert Equation.
I described the experience and what i've done so far... But I don't know how to link This tension T with my vibrators and the bowl. Do you have any idea?

[image]

Regards

Comment: lead is a lousy electric conductor $208n\Omega \cdot m$ but gold is among the best  $22.1 n\Omega \cdot m$, so use attenuation to discriminate between them

Comment: Sure there are much easier ways to measure this, but I think it's an interesting question

Comment: If you can submerge the object in water (as per your diagram) you can measure it's volume and by measuring it's weight you will get you density.  The rest seems needlessly complex.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine if you had to discriminate between a few micro- or milli-grams of stripline made of lead or gold deposited on the surface of glass carrier, say, then conductivity is a natural way of testing; submerging it in water a la Archimedes would be hopeless.

Comment: Yes, but my goal was to find it using waves...

Comment: @hyportnex Just pointing out something the OP has in their own diagram.  Not suggesting conductivity testing isn't useful.